# How to build two ".so" files in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

My question is:
I have used ndk to develop some functions, when built, it created a `.so` file in `libs/armeabi`.
 Now I needed to add another `.so` file from others. 
I only copied the `.so` to my dir `libs/armeabi`, then built it.
 The `.so` file was missing and I only had mine.

I do not kown why it happens. Should I need to config my `Android.mk` file, or any else?

Comment: using NDK,read its documentation

Comment: in addition to that, there are a lot of samples that are bundled with NDK.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the libs folder is cleaned when you run the ndk-build!

Edit your Android.mk and add this:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := MYOTHERSO-prebuilt 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := [relative path to your other .so]/lib[change to your lib name].so 
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := [relative path to your other .so include files]
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

You should store the .so file on another path (not on libs/armeabi folder) in order to reference it from your Android.mk. During ndk-build it will be copied to libs/armeabi folder.